# Mainframe data extraction

Tags: excel, extract, mainframe

I have a mainframe application that is called sunet, here are some records. 
I want to extract data in excel using vba macros. I have tried by my own but i have no idea how to make connection between mainframe and excel. Please advise me how to do this. 
Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough information here about your exact situation for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: Are you able to connect to and retrieve the records from the mainframe manually?

Comment: Try this google search: excel pull data from mainframe with vba. It has various links that could be useful.

Comment: tried [ Data > GetExternalData ] ?

Comment: What is needed is more information on what you intend to connect to.  For instance, are you trying to interact with a web-service, access a dataset (read a file), or connect to Db2.  If you can help us understand more of the nature of what you are trying to accomplish you'll be able to get more assistance.  Also, very important, what have you tried and why did it now work?  Error messages, etc.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/rants/blob/master/advice-reading-mainframe-data.md) are some things to consider when updating your question with more information.

Comment: You need to talk to your colleagues and DBAs on how to connect to the database(s) from a PC. As this appears to be an internal corporate system, we cannot help you with the basics that form the foundation of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, sorry.  I expect your data is on the mainframe.

It sounds like you want an ODBC connection to a database. You will need to check with your architects or DBA's for specifics, e.g. does the DBMS product have a "client side" component you can direct this through? Otherwise performance and sociability may be a concern. There are better 3rd party clients, are you committed to VBA?

The name of your application (or the stage of the life cycle is not important).
The size of your data is very important. How many hundred million records?

**You could alternatively** pull the data all at once. You may be allowed access to a backup.

There are a number of ways data can be pulled from the mainframe. You can format it into csv first, or you may have a language that will build an xls file. Traditionally the MS product was Access back in the days when excel had a restrictive limit on the number of records (50K?), and if you want an ODBC connection

1. IND$FILE transfer from ISPF Panel 3.6 by means of a TN3270 terminal on your desktop. If your shop is sophisticated, you may have a cli script as well.
2. sftp transfer, SSH, SCP, Telnet and bear in mind you will need a landing area.
3. Any managed Queue product, such as MQSeries.
4. Media, even optical.
5. You may have a transmission product such as CA-XCOM.

This is bread and butter stuff, even if you have EBCDIC on a Wintel stack you can decode():encode() with Python. I would expect you to be IBM500, but you should confirm this as well.

So yes, colleagues, or even search your source repositories for JCL with these keywords.